# "unrecognized escape in character string" on R startup

Tags: windows, windows-10, r, rstudio

I get this error first thing when I start an R session (rterm, rgui, rstudio all of them). I've cleared the `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` files and they have nothing setting paths in them.

The exact error can be seen in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N41kA.png). The 2 prints are my attempts at debugging this. They are from the `Rprofile.site` and `.Rprofile` (user file) respectively. The error is printed before all these files are read so I'm not sure what's causing it.

I'm on Windows 10 and I know R and Windows have issues with paths so that might be relevant maybe.

Comment: I can't embed the image so it's a link.

Answer (score 0):

Try also deleting any `.RData` file in the directory your project is in.

You could also disable the *restore workspace on startup* option in your RStudio options if you want to start the session from there.

If that doesn't work then consider modifying the working directory to use forward slashes instead of backslashes since backslashes might get interpreted as escape characters. You can:

1. Make use of the setwd() command: `setwd("C:/workingdir")`
2. Adjust your Rstudio settings under Tools > Options by specifying the *Default working directory (when not in project)*

See also: http://www.pradeepadiga.me/blog/2017/01/15/working-with-directories-in-r/

Comment: The issue isn't with rStudio. I get the same error even if I run R from the command line. Also as mentioned in the question, I'm aware of the slash inconsistency in Windows. If I just know _where_ the error is being generated, I can change the slash.